# Truffle test: how to get the block number of deployed contract?

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-test

In my test I would like to get the block or block number of when the contract was deployed.

```
const instance = await MyContract.deployed()
const contractDeploymentBlockNumber = await instance.?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using

```
truffle develop
> migrate
```

or

```
truffle migrate
```

It returns the transaction hash for a specific object, i.e.

```
0x95aadab5fdd4c06dbf0e27601bd3a4c2da2ea244a7506189864f4465351fe3dc
```

So, you can get the block number for that contract deployment using

```
const txBlock = await Migrations.web3.eth.getTransaction('0x95aadab5fdd4c06dbf0e27601bd3a4c2da2ea244a7506189864f4465351fe3dc');
console.log(txBlock.blockNumber);
```

Comment: He is referring to truffle test for a specific deployed contract, not common web3.js code for current block.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```js
module.exports = function(deployer) {
  const MyContract = artifacts.require("MyContract");
  await deployer.deploy(MyContract);
  const instance = await MyContract.deployed();
  const address = instance.address;
  const txHash = MyContract.transactionHash;
  const blockNumber = (await MyContract.web3.eth.getTransaction(hash)).blockNumber;
};
```